# I can't leave the logo fixed when I scroll down

Tags: html, css, header, responsive, sidebar

First of all, excuse my english (I'm argentinian :)
I'm making one of my first web pages, and I'm having a problem with the header.
I'm trying to do something like this:

https://pallarols.com.ar/

I like the side menu, and that when viewed on mobile, the site transforms into a header with the logo centered and the menu is hidden, to be activated with a button.

I have almost done everything, but I have a little problem with the header in the normal view (not in mobile). When I scroll down, the logo goes up, but I want it to stay fixed and only move the content. But if I put the header with position:fixed then the content stays below the header.

This is my code:

```
<body>
    <header>
      <img src="images/logo.png" class="logo" />
    </header>

    <div class="sidebar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Mis Obras</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Talleres</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor...</p>
    </div>

    <div class="menu-toggle">&#9776;</div>

    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
  </body>
```

```
html {
  height: 100vh;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0 0 20px;
  background-color: wheat;
}
.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 90vh;
  background-color: #222;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: transform 0.1s ease-in-out;
}
.content{
  margin-left: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  height: 100vh;
}

.menu-toggle {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  display: none;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {

  header {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 0 0 0;
  }

  .content{
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  
  .sidebar {
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }

  .sidebar.active {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }

  .menu-toggle {
    display: block;
  }
```

Below I put some screenshots to better understand the problem (I have put background colors to each element temporarily, to be able to visualize it better):

[normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dFuF.png)

[scroll down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8y2M.png)

I guess another option would be to place the header inside the sidebar, but this way I can't make it display as a header centered in the mobile view, since the sidebar is hidden.

Could you give me a clue on how to solve it? It has become difficult for me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but may i suggest if it's not already fixed? I'm not sure if i can help but would you try to add in your css?then make the position of you header to absolute.

let say,

```
.header{ position: absolute; top: 0; }
```

I hope in somehow i can help.